# Give values from sub select and re-enter back in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My dbo.Report table has a column called **Name**. I need to somehow select the Name column in my sub select. How can I get the Name values from the sub select as well? Once I have those I need to be able to run another select query such as this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyOtherTable WHERE Name = @pName
```

where @pName being a newly created variable with values from the sub-select possibly?? I'm not sure how that works. Or something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyOtherTable WHERE Name IN (the values from my sub select go here)
```

PROC:

```
SELECT        ListingInfo, 
              COALESCE((SELECT SUM(ListingViews) 
              FROM dbo.Report
              WHERE (ID = @pID) 
              AND (DateEntered BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, 0, @pFromDate) AND DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @pToDate)-1)
              GROUP BY ID), 0) AS 'Views'
FROM dbo.Reporting r
INNER JOIN dbo.Listings l ON (r.ID = l.ID)
WHERE (r.ID = @pID)
AND l.TypeCode = 20
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a table variable to store your names.

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE
(
  Name varchar(250),
  SomeInt int
)

INSERT INTO @Names (Name, SomeInt)
SELECT Name, sum(ListingViews)
FROM WhateverTable
GROUP BY Name

SELECT * FROM OtherTable WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM @Names)
```

You can go on to use @Names as if it were any other table, and if you use it in a stored procedure, it will automatically handle the clean up of the table variable when it ends.

Comment: Ok great. How can I get the Names from of my sub-select?

Comment: Well, if I understand you correctly, you would insert the results of the sub-select into @Names.  At that point, you can use "SELECT Name FROM @Names" to get all the Names from the sub-select.

Comment: How do I get those results of Names in my sub-select to @Names? It won't let me do `COALESCE((SELECT Names, SUM(ListingViews)`

Comment: Well for the table variable, you would have to add as many columns as you were including in your SELECT statement, I have edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? 
Or what else do you need?
Didn't understand it at all, sorry.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyOtherTable 
WHERE Name IN (SELECT name FROM Table WHERE Name = @pName)
```

**Edit:**
Something like this?

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), name
 FROM MyOtherTable O,  Table T
 WHERE O.Name = T.NAME
 AND T.NAME = @pName
 group by name
```

Comment: I need to get a COUNT and Names from my sub-select? How can I get multiple values from that?

Comment: What is your real question, I updated my answer, but still dont understand, you dind't tell anythign abour your PROC inthe question what it should do , that it is not doing?